# Javascript stop repeating collision detection in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, collision-detection

I'm trying to do some simple collisions in javascript and html5 canvas. So far I have this:

```
  checkCollision = (function(){
        var l, i, ni,dis = 0;
        var ob1,ob2 = {};

        return function(){
            //collisions is the array holding all the objects
            l = collisions.length;
            i = 0;
            ni = 1;
            while(i<l){
                //grab the first object
                ob1 = collisions[i];

                while(ni<l){
                    //get the object to check against
                    ob2 = collisions[ni];
                    //find the distance between the two
                    dis = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((ob1.pos[0]-ob2.pos[0]),2)+Math.pow((ob1.pos[1]-ob2.pos[1]),2));
                    //rad is the radius
                    if(ob1.rad+ob2.rad >= dis){
                        console.log("collision")
                    }

                    //move forward second increment
                    ni++;
                }

                i++;
                //keep one place ahead
                ni=i+1;
            }
        };

    })();
```

I did it without any help of any kind, but now I guess my brain is too much mush to figure this last part out. The collision is happening every frame, which I don't want. I just want it to fire once when the collision first happens. I've tried by giving each object a collide variable that's true if there's already a collision but it's not working very well. Some it fires once and some it fires constantly. 
Does anyone have any pointers?

Comment: By the way this is just simple circular collision

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "happening every frame"? The algorithm seems ok, but there doesn't seem to be any conesquence from the collision, it is just logged. Do you want to break out of the loop?

Some comments that have nothing to do with your issue but might make your code a bit more readable and concise:

```
>   checkCollision = (function(){
>         var l, i, ni,dis = 0;
>         var ob1,ob2 = {};
```

I don't know why you initialise *dis* and *ob2*, they are assigned values later. Using a closure like this means that the values persist to subesquent calls until new values are assigned. Is the closure really needed? It may be a performance hit for animations like this.

```
>             ni = 1;
>             while(i<l){
```

You can put *ni* after the while, like this:

```
        while(i < l){
            ni = i + 1;
```

and get rid of the last `ni = i + 1`. You can also do:

```
>             ob1 = collisions[i++];
```

and get rid of the last `i++;`, an do the same for *ni* when assigning to *ob2*.

Doing the above reduces the number of lines of code so it is more digestable, e.g.

```
function checkCollision() {
    var ni, dis, ob1, ob2;
    //collisions is the array holding all the objects
    var l = collisions.length;
    var i = 0;

    while (i < l) {
        ni = i + 1;
        //grab the first object
        ob1 = collisions[i++];

        while (ni < l) {
            //get the object to check against
            ob2 = collisions[ni++];
            //find the distance between the two
            dis = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((ob1.pos[0] - ob2.pos[0]), 2) + 
                            Math.pow((ob1.pos[1] - ob2.pos[1]), 2));
            //rad is the radius
            if (ob1.rad + ob2.rad >= dis) {
                console.log("collision");

                // And what else?

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's really draft code, I also set those variables to persist so they won't be recreated every frame of the game. That's how often this is run. It's run about 25 times a second and I don't want the collision to fire every time it happens. Say I reverse ob1's xvelocity, it'll just bounce because the collision happens every time and not just the first time.

Comment: let me try to explain it better haha, I want it to fire once for each collision that is *unique*. Otherwise if the objects get too close together and say I implement a bounce, the two objects shake and get stuck together since it's constantly making them bounce

Comment: @Isaiah: But wouldn't bouncing make them further apart therefore preventing them from colliding in the next frame? I think your problem is that you haven't implemented the bounce yet.

Comment: well actually I have. This is taken out of a much bigger project. I don't want to include much of the full code because it's going to be a commercial product and i'm not so sure the company will like that. The problem is that some sprites would spawn on each other, or they would move too fast sometimes for the collision to keep up and get stuck in each other

Comment: In that case, only "bounce" them if it will take them further away from each other. I'm sure there's some cool vector maths that will tell you if their vectors are converging or diverging. Or you can remember their last positions and see if the distance between them is getting smaller or greater. If it's getting smaller, bounce them. If it's getting greater, don't.